# Is there a best practice when using nfs over GCEPersistentDisk?

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, persistent-volumes, google-persistent-disk

I'm a software developer who got to a point where I need to mount a Persistent Volume with ReadWriteMany access mode in multiple nodes, in my GKE Cluster.

I'm well aware that [GCEPersistentDisk](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#access-modes) does not support such access mode, so I turned to [NFS](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#nfs) instead.

My main question is what considered best practice to overcome this GCEPersistentDisk limitation?

I did a some research before posting this question, but I could not find a clear fit solution.
Allow me to list some of the options found and their respective cons:

- Nfs using [helm chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/nfs-server-provisioner) - seems great but it's deprecated. Why? What's wrong with this method?
- nfs-subdir-external-provisioner [chart](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner) - requires an NFS server installed and I'm not sure how to. In addition it's [pitfalls](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/nfs-subdir-external-provisioner#nfs-provisioner-limitationspitfalls) are a major concern.
- Google [Filestore](https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/accessing-fileshares) - seems easy to use but its minimum size is 1 Tb which will result in expensive & major unused memory.
- Turn to [GlusterFs](https://www.gluster.org/) instead of NFS - seems complicated to install & maintain.

Many Thanks to all involved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found out that you can mount GCS and then access blobs in it using: [gcsfuse](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/)

For future references - there are equivalents in [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) (which supports also GCS, minio, etc).

Sorry if I spammed.